# GODOT Change scene in node

Tags: 2d, scene, godot

I will change a scene on button click. But not change the main scene with button.

Node structure:

```
main
- scene (with childs)
- button
```

button.gd:

```
func pressed():
    get_node("scene").change_scene("res://second_scene.tscn")
```

It doesn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep track of the current scene in a global variable called `current_scene` and try something like this:

```
func change_scene(scene_path):
    call_deferred("change_scene_deferred", scene_path) # waits until an idle period when nodes can be removed safely


func change_scene_deferred(scene_path):
    # remove current scene
    current_scene.free()
    print("FREED CURRENT SCENE")

    # instance new scene
    var s = load(scene_path)
    current_scene = s.instance()
    print("INSTANCED NEW SCENE")

    # add new scene to main node
    get_tree().get_root().get_node("Main").add_child(current_scene)
    print("ADDED SCENE TO Main")
```

Answer (score 0):

Search and try.... 
I think this is a bad solution:

```
func pressed():
    var main= get_tree().get_root().get_node("main")
    var scene = get_tree().get_root().get_node("main/scene")
    main.remove_child(scene)

    var next_scene_resource = load("res://second_scene.tscn")
    var next_scene = next_scene_resource.instance()
    main.add_child(next_scene)
```

Comment: I see an attempt to edit this answer with an assessment of the code. GameViewer, if this is you attempting to update your answer, [please merge your accounts](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can edit posts under your own ID. If this was another user wanting to share a critique of the code, please use the commenting or voting features, rather than modifying the answer itself, or suggest an edit with a correction to the issue.